# Keep sessions between private tabs

Tags: macos, safari

I am used to of the old private browsing mode in Safari, where you can keep a login session between tabs. But since this new Safari came with Yosemite, the tabs maintain their own sessions.

Is there any way I can keep the login session between safari private tabs till the private window closes, just like how Google Chrome does?

Comment: Why the hell you want to do this? Chrome users have been striving this feature [for years](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24690) and you have it OOTB

Comment: @Suncatcher Why the hell do you want to have any other flavour in ice-cream when vanilla exists? Different user different requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible. Safari Private Browsing tabs and windows do not share any session data and are completely independent.

From the [Apple Support KB "Safari for Mac: Use Private Browsing windows in Safari"](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph21413?locale=en_US):

- Each tab in the window is isolated from the others, so websites you view in one tab can’t track your browsing in other tabs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. If I ⌘-click a link in a Private Browsing tab, the new tab is logged out of whichever service.

Comment: @Elliott I don't remember what I was doing when I wrote this answer, but you're true now. Edited answer, thanks.

Comment: @grg I think it's still the case. When you click on a link and it takes you to a new tab, it'll keep cookies. This is the case because otherwise, say you needed to change an account setting by clicking a link that took you to a new tab. If the new tab started off as a blank slate, it would be impossible for you to change that setting. To prevent this shared cookies are allowed between those tabs.